# how can i get values ​in array as parameters in React (for axios)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios

my array like this

**I want it to get the parameters dynamically because their number can change**

const [array , setArray]= useState([])

I have arrays in an array, when I import them with map, the last such array comes and I have to save its contents to the database.

example : array[0]

(6) ['aaa', 'bb', 'cc', -0.08, 3661, 'dd']

```
  const response = await axios.post(API_URL , {
        ???
    });
    return response.data;
```

how can i send it to axiosa one by one as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

if you always know the correct sequence of that array, you can directly set the properties you need

```js
const [array , setArray]= useState(['aaa', 'bb', 'cc', -0.08, 3661, 'dd'])
const response = await axios.post(API_URL , {
      date: array[0],
      receiptNo: array[1],
      //etc
  });
 return response.data;
```

If this is not what you are looking for, then please give a more detailed description.

Comment: yes thank you,  but I couldn't get it when I rotated it dynamically in the map, actually I wanted to learn it